# Ruby - Sum Results of Select()

Tags: ruby, math, functional-programming

I'm doing www.eulerproject.net, the first problem:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10, that are multiples of 3
>   or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9.  The sum of these multiples is 23.   Find
>   the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The following is the code I have so far.

```
(3..999).to_a.select do |x|
   x % 3.0 == 0 || x % 5.0 == 0
end
```

It would be easy to append the numbers into an array, but how can this be done by how can this be done by chaining a method onto the end of this.  Something like

```
p start loop
  do stuff
end.sum
```

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), something you need to guard against. The problem is to determine a sum. You have assumed that `select` is needed, so you've expressed you question in terms of `select`, yet there are methods to do this that don't involve `select`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question - yes, you can chain the method like you've shown.

```
(3..999).to_a.select do |x|
   x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 # you don't have to use floats here, integers would work
end.inject(:+)
#=> 233168
```

The rule of a style guides is to NOT to chain methods to multiline `do` `end` blocks, but it is a working code.

It's the same as writing

```
 (3..999).to_a.select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.inject(:+)
 #=>233168
```

[Array#`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) is an ActiveSupport method, not Ruby's, but I think you should use Ruby's methods in eulerproject tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You are summing arithmetic series, so there is no need to iterate:

```
def sum(n,m)
  p = n/m
  m*p*(1+p)/2
end

n = 999
sum(n,3) + sum(n,5) - sum(n,15)
  #=> 233168
```

Consider:

```
n = 100
m =   3
p = 100/3 #=> 33

sum(100,3) = 3 + 6 + 9 +...+ 99
           = 3 * (1 + 2 +...+ p)
           = 3 * p(1+p)/2
```

We need to subtract `sum(100,15)` because `sum(100,3) + sum(100,5)` double-counts:

```
sum(100,15) = 15 + 30 + 45 + 60 + 75 + 90
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the sum of array, you can do like this:

```
(3..999).inject(0) { |sum, e| e % 3 == 0 || e % 5 == 0 ? sum += e : sum }
=> 233168
```

it just need once loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the to_a, since calling 'select' to (3..999) will still return an array regardless.
Andrey's answer is the most compact one with :

`(3..999).select{ |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.inject(:+)`